# How to solve this ODE: ${y'}^4+y^2=y^4$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I know there is a simple and crude way to solve it:

$$y'=(y^4-y^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}\Rightarrow(y^4-y^2)^{-\frac{1}{4}}dy=dx$$
But this indefinite integral is really too hard to calculate. Maybe there is a simpler way, but I don’t know how to do it. Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: $y=0,\pm 1$ are all solutions

Comment: @NinadMunshi: Surely there are others too! With $y(0)=c$, where $|c|>1$, you get non-constant solutions.

Comment: I don't thing there's any way of getting round that integration. If there were a simple solution to the ODE, then the integral ought to be simple to calculate too.

Comment: It cound be related to the incomplete beta function through the substitution $z=y^{-2}$.

Answer (score 5):

Inspired by the phase space mapping of this differential equation almost being a pseudo hyperbola of sorts, consider guessing a solution of the form $y = \pm \cosh f(x)$ for some unknown $f$ (there is no loss of solutions due to choice of branch because $y^4 - (y')^4 = y^2 > 0$ implies $y$ must always stay the same sign). This gives us the following equation

$$\sinh^4 f(x) \cdot (f')^4 + \cosh^2 f(x) = \cosh^4 f(x)$$

$$ \implies \cosh^2 f(x) - \sinh^2 f(x) \cdot \left[\tanh^2 f(x) \cdot (f')^4\right] = 1$$

We get exactly our solution under the condition $1 = \tanh^2 f(x) \cdot (f')^4$. For the moment we can restrict our attention to solutions to where $f'$ is nonnegative to get

$$1 = \sqrt{|\tanh f(x)|}\cdot f'(x) \implies x + C = \left(\tanh^{-1}\sqrt{|\tanh f|}-\tan^{-1}\sqrt{|\tanh f|}\right)\operatorname{sgn} f$$

(We can also always of course "go backwards" and insert a $\pm$ to account for $f' < 0$ solutions). Inserting $f = \pm\cosh^{-1} |y|$, we get our solutions

$$x+C = \pm\left(\tanh^{-1}\sqrt[4]{\frac{y^2-1}{y^2}} - \tan^{-1}\sqrt[4]{\frac{y^2-1}{y^2}}\right)\operatorname{sgn}\left(y\right)$$

This is separate from the already known constant solutions, $y=0,\pm 1$.